# How to design software for Linux in relation to Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, porting

I have an application that I've written for Windows which I am porting to Linux (Ubuntu to be specific). The problem is that I have always just used Linux, never really developed for it. More specifically, I dont understand the fundamental layout of the system. For example, where should I install my software? I want it to be accessible to all users, but I need write permission to the area to edit my data files. Furthermore, how can I determine in a programmatic way, where the software was installed (not simply where its being called from)? In windows, I use the registry to locate my configuration file which has all of the relevant information, but there is no registry in Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) (misnamed -- it is not a standard) will be very helpful to you; it clearly describes administrator preferences for where data should live.

Since you're first packaging your software, I'd like to recommend doing *very little*. Debian, Ubuntu, Red Hat, SuSE, Mandriva, Arch, Annvix, Openwall, PLD, etc., all have their own little idiosyncrasies about how software should be best packaged.

**Building**

Your best bet is to provide a source tarball that *builds* and hope users or packagers for those distributions pick it up and package it for you. Users will probably be fine with downloading a tarball, unpacking, compiling, and installing.

For building your software, [`make(1)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) is the usual standard. Other tools exists, but this one is available everywhere, and pretty reasonable. (Even if the syntax is **cranky**.) Users will expect to be able to run: `make ; make install` or `./configure ; make ; make install` to build and install your software into `/usr/local` by default. (`./configure` is part of the [autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) toolchain; especially nice for providing `./configure --prefix=/opt/foo` to allow users to change where the software gets installed with one command line parameter. I'd try to avoid the autotools as far as you can, but at some point, it is easier to write portable software *with* them than *without* them.)

**Packaging**

If you really do want to provide one-stop-packaging, then the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) will provide the canonical rules for how to package your software. The [Debian New Maintainers Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) will provide a kinder, gentler, walkthrough of the tools unique to building packages for Debian and Debian-derived systems.

[Ubuntu's Packaging Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) may have details specific to Ubuntu. (I haven't read it yet.)

**Configuration**

When it comes to your application's configuration file, typically a file is stored in `/etc/<foo>` where `<foo>` represents the program / package. See `/etc/resolv.conf` for details on name resolution, `/etc/fstab` for a list of devices that contain filesystems and where to mount them, `/etc/sudoers` for the `sudo(8)` configuration, `/etc/apt/` for the `apt(8)` package management system, etc.

Sometimes applications also provide per-user configuration; those config files are often stored in `~/.foorc` or `~/.foo/`, in case an entire directory is more useful than a file. (See `~/.vim/`, `~/.mozilla/`, `~/.profile`, etc.)

If you also wanted to provide a `-c <filename>` command line option to tell your program to use a non-standard configuration file, that sometimes comes in *real* handy. (Especially if your users can run `foo -c /dev/null` to start up with completely default configuration.)

**Data files**

Users will store their data in their home directory. You don't need to do anything about this; just be sure to start your directory navigation boxes with `getenv("HOME")` or load your configuration files via `sprintf(config_dir, "%s/%s/config", getenv("HOME"), ".application");` or something similar. (They won't have permissions to write anywhere but their home directory and `/tmp/` at most sites.)

Sometimes all the data can be stored in a hidden file or directory; `ssh(1)` for example, keeps all its data in `~/.ssh/`. Typically, users want the default kry name from `ssh-keygen(1)` so `ssh-agent(1)` can find the key with the minimum of fuss. (It uses `~/.ssh/id_rsa` by default.) The `shotwell(1)` photo manager provides a *managed* experience, similar to `iPhoto.app` from Apple. It lets users choose a starting directory, but otherwise organizes files and directories within as it sees fit.

If your application is a general purpose program, you'll probably let your users select their own filenames. If they want to store data directly to a memory stick mounted in `/dev` or `/media` or a remote filesystem mounted into `/automount/blah`, their home directories, a `/srv/` directory for content served on the machine, or `/tmp/`, let them. It's up to users to pick reasonable filenames and directories for their data. It is up to users to have proper permissions *already*. (Don't try to provide mechanisms for users to write in locations they don't have privileges.)

**Application file installation and ownership**

There are two common ways to install an application on a Linux system:

1. The administrator installs it once, for everyone. This is usual. The programs are *owned* by `root` or `bin` or `adm` or some similar account. The programs *run* as whichever user executes them, so they get the user's privileges for creating and reading files. If they are packaged with distribution packaging files, executables will typically live in `/usr/bin/`, libraries in `/usr/lib/`, and non-object-files (images, schemas, etc.) will live in `/usr/share/`. (`/bin/` and `/lib/` are for applications needed at early boot or for rescue environments. `/usr` might be common to all machines in a network, mounted read-only late in the boot up process.) (See the FHS for full details.)

   If the programs are unpackaged, then `/usr/local/` will be the starting point: `/usr/local/bin/`, `/usr/local/lib/`, `/usr/local/share/`, etc. Some administrators prefer `/opt/`.
2. Users install applications into their home directory. This is less common, but many users will have a `~/bin/` directory where they store shell scripts or programs they write, or link in programs from a `~/Local/<foo>/` directory. (There is nothing magic about that name. It was just the first thing I thought of years ago. Others choose other names.) This is where `./configure --prefix=~/Local/blah` pays for itself.)

Comment: I love the effort and long answer, but two things are missing: 1. What about data files? Where do they go? 2. If the administrator installs the software, where does it go?

Comment: @chacham15, I expanded details a little further -- let me know if it helps. You might want to take a look at the `stow` package, which can make managing a `/usr/local/` directory easier.

Comment: Yes, a lot better, but I was unclear. The program itself has 2 sets of data that it needs to store all of which isnt managed by the user and the user shouldnt need to worry about. 1: Global information pertaining to the application (i.e. user independent information) and 2: Information pertaining to the user. I dont want either of these in a user visible directory because the user shouldnt be messing with or even see these files. So, where do I put them?

Comment: The usual Unix philosophy is that all data files should be in an open file format that users can manipulate external to the program, should the need arise. That's why the `mbox` mail box format is so popular: there are dozens of tools to support it. That's why almost all configuration files are simple plain text -- so simple tools can modify them: via [chef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_(software)) or [puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)) or `rdist` or `git(1)` -- or use standard SQLite3 or Berkeley DB -- again, so we can use standard tools.

Comment: If the user _really_ shouldn't have access to the data, you can always store it on your own servers, and have your software manipulate it all remotely. But it sure wouldn't feel very _native_ if the user can't easy make a backup of it, keep it under version control, or remove it all when they'd rather start from a clean slate.

Comment: The file contains confidential information, and therefore is encrypted. No other application should be able to have access to the information. The whole point is that the user does have access to the information, but he HAS to go through my app to do it. Lastly, I dont want the file to be touched by anyone but the application for the sake of security, so Id rather it not be in a standard user-visible location.

Comment: Fair enough; however, `root` has complete access to all data on the machine. A [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tool such as  [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/) can prevent `root` from reading specific files; but physical control grants complete access to all files on the machine, even with these tools.

Comment: You also have to trust your users to not debug your application with `strace(1)`, `ltrace(1)`, `gdb(1)`, or `ptrace(2)`. They could attach a debugger as you're decrypting data retrieved from your servers, and read the plaintext out of memory, if they are so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, everything is text i.e. ASCII.

Configuration is stored in configuration files which normally have .conf extension and stored in /etc folder.

The executable of your application normally resides in `/usr/bin` folder.  The data files of your application can go to `/usr/lib` or folder in `/usr/` folder.

It is important to consider which language you are writing your application in. In C/C++ a custom `makefile` is used to do installation which copies these files in respective folders. The location of installation can be tracked by tracking the .conf file and storing the location while generation using bash script.

You should really know bash scripting in order to automate this everything.

Comment: Must all configuration files go there? Or could they be installed elsewhere?

Comment: Configuration usually lives in `/etc/` or user home directories, depending if it is site-wide or per-user configuration options.